# CRM 2011, Find workflow that created email

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've been tasked to find out which workflow has a task that creates a certain email.  The email that is created is nothing special, all it has is the subject line of Test and the contact and owner information.  Since we have a large number of processes is it possible to trace one of these created emails back to the workflow that created it?

Thanks

Comment: Using GUI, plugin, JS or desktop application?

Comment: For clarification, I can look at either the GUI through IE or I have access to the CRM SQL database as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to look at the email and know which workflow created it. But if you try the following you should be able to get pretty close or at least narrow down your field of search.

If you know when the email was created, the workflow will have been running around that timeframe. So, go to: CRM > Settings > System Jobs, this will show all the workflows and asynchronous tasks that were running so just find ones near the created on of the email and open them up. You can see in the 'process progress' section what steps the workflow has performed and if it has created anything it will show the email. So you should be able to confirm it that way. If that doesn’t work (e.g. because the system jobs are cleared down regularly).

Then you can see what has a dependency on the email, go to: CRM > Settings > Customisations > Customise the System > Entities > Email > Show Dependencies, this will show any processes that do something with an email, so assuming there isn’t 100s you can just look at them manually to find the right one.

Comment: This helped us track it down the actual root cause of the issue. When we imported a number of contact records we had a certain test workflow activated. Shortly after the import the workflow was placed back in draft. When the imported contact records were merged with web created records the activity was updated, giving the impression that the email was created again. We were able to fix this by doing an advanced find on activities with the email subject and deleting them.  Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a marker into the message body or the subject using a code that corresponds to the workflow that created the mail. I haven't built such a thing myself so it's just a suggestion.